Lambda is not iterated in an Array
I'm stuck in a situation like the one you can see here:






































11/04/2017
$1,000.00

2017
1000



01/01/2018
$10,002.00

2018
0



01/07/2018
$10,002.00

2019
0



01/01/2019
$1,000.00

2020
0



01/06/2019
$100.00

2021
0



01/01/2020
$1,000.00

2022
0



01/01/2021
$10,008.00

2023
0



01/01/2022
$1,000.00

2024
0



12/09/2022
$1,000.00






01/01/2023
$800.00






01/01/2024
$1,000.00






What I'm trying to achieve is selecting all unique ranges of years in B, and for them making a sum of C values in F.
As it stands the filter in uniques works well, but something is not working with the sum, and I don't get what I'm doing wrong, the table in E:F is created with this formula:
=MAP(UNIQUE(INDEX(RIGHT(B5:B15,4))), UNIQUE(INDEX(RIGHT(B5:B15,2))) , lambda(a, b, {a,  SUMIF(RIGHT(B5:B15,4),a,C5:C15)}))

Is maybe a in the lambda not iterable?
Thank you for your help

To easily take a copy of your sample data & test formulas (instead of winging it from screenshots), the recommended method is to create a markdown table. Use this tool to create the markdown_format & add it to your question. Additionally you can also share a sample sheet showcasing your input with realistic-demo data & expected output(manually entered). You may also use the anonymous blank sheet maker to ease the process of sharing

@rockinfreakshow thank you for the hint, edited with markdown table


You may try:
=map(unique(sort(year(B5:B15))),lambda(Σ,{Σ,sum(ifna(filter(C:C,year(B:B)=Σ)))}))


you can also replace the part
sum(ifna(filter(C:C,year(B:B)=Σ)))

with
sumif(index(year(B:B)),Σ,C:C)


thank you, works like a charm.
year() way better than a substring.
is the Σ that was missing from my side, is that the key to let that iterate through the array? i did'nt found it in docs

You used a,b as identifiers; I used Σ as identifier for just convenience factor. Your formula should work as well if modified as such: =MAP(UNIQUE(INDEX(RIGHT(B5:B15,4))),lambda(a,{a,SUMIF(index(RIGHT(B5:B15,4)),a,C5:C15)}))

You don't need LAMBDA for this, you can simply use:
=SORT(LET(y,YEAR(B5:B15),u,UNIQUE(y),{u,SUMIF(y,u,C5:C15)}))


If you want it to work with open ranges, use:
=SORT(LET(y,YEAR(TOCOL(B5:B,1)),u,UNIQUE(y),{u,SUMIF(y,u,C5:C)}))


This type of aggregation is usually easiest to do with query(), like this:
=query(B5:C, "select year(B), sum(C) where B is not null group by year(B)", 0)

See query().
